# Azure Blueprint invalid artifacts function

Tags: azure, azure-blueprints

I'm developing an Azure Blueprint with three artifacts:

- A log analytics workspace
- Two policy assignments that reference this log analytics workspace

[image: Artifacts]

To be able to reference log analytics workspace in policy assignments, I exported resource id of this log analytics  workspace

```
  "outputs": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', variables('workspaces_manage_log_analytics_name'))]"
    }
  }
```

In policy assignments, I tried to refer to the log analytics workspace id with `[artifacts('LogAnalyticsWorkspace').outputs.id]`, but ended with an error

[image]

This error says this reference is invalid. I checked [artifacts function document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/azure/governance/blueprints/reference/blueprint-functions#artifacts), but with no luck to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In portal, users can assign "display name", but not "name" to artifacts. If users want to assign "name" to an artifact, they need to [use Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/azure/governance/blueprints/how-to/import-export-ps) to export blueprint, rename json file, and import the modified blueprint.

For the question, "LogAnalyticsWorkspace" is not a "name", but only a "display name". You need to assign "name" by yourself.